# Findind model that belongs to two models with a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application that has `subtasks`, `subattributes`, and `weights`.

A `subtask` can have many `subattributes` **via** `weights` and can have many `weights`.

A `subattribute` can have many `subtasks` **via** `weights` and can have many `weights`.

A `weight` can belong to both a `subtask` and a `subattribute`.

Right now I am trying to loop through the collection print the weight. However, I am having issues acutally figuring out how to get the specific weights. Here's what I have:

```
<% @subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
   <% @subattributes.each do |subattribute| %>
      <% if subattribute.subtasks.include (subtask) %>
           #find the weight of that subattribute that's associated with that subtask
      <% else %>
         #create a new weight associated with the subattribute and subtask
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Any suggestions. This is my first rails app and I didn't design the backend because I personally would have thought it easier to just have weight be a field in subattribute. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to give your question a better title. Also it will help of you add the relevant lines of you models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
   <% @subattributes.each do |subattribute| %>
      <% if subattribute.subtasks.include?(subtask) %>
         #find the weight of that subattribute that's associated with that subtask
           <% Weight.where(subattribute_id: subattribute.id,subtask_id: subtask.id).first %>
      <% else %>
          #create a new weight associated with the subattribute and subtask
          <% Weight.create(subattribute_id: subattribute.id,subtask_id: subtask.id) %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So question, how would I get a field using that where? I tried <%Weight.where(subattribute_id: subattribute.id,subtask_id: subtask.is).first.capability %> but got an undefined method error.

Comment: @MeganWoodruff I had a typo. It should be `subtask.id` instead of `subtask.is`. Updated the above answer

Comment: Ahhh got it! Thanks so much! I had no idea this where even existed! Accepting and voting up!

Comment: one last question, how would I add that create to a link_to for creating a new weight record?

Comment: @MeganWoodruff There is a lot of ways to accomplish this. A conventional way of doing this: `<%= link_to "Add Weight", new_weight_path(subattribute_id: subattribute.id,subtask_id: subtask.id) %>` . To support this you must have **routes** like `resources :weights` and a `WeightsController` with `new` and `create` action. `new` action would render `new.html.erb` where you can have a form to create weights by setting hidden fields like `<%= f.hidden_field :subattribute_id, params[:subattribute_id] %>` & `<%= f.hidden_field :subtask_id, params[:subtask_id] %>` . create weights in `create` action